# Post to AmazonAWS Kinesis Stream Using Query String Authentication

Tags: javascript, authentication, post, amazon-web-services

I've got the interesting (and theoretically impossible) task of getting AmazonAWS Kinesis analytics from IE 8 and 9. According to Amazon's own SDK, this is not possible since `XDomainRequest` does not allow custom headers. Contrary to this statement, however, [AmazonAWS allows you to authenticate using query string parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-get-query-string). My goal was to write a shim for `XMLHttpRequest` which utilized the `XDomainRequest` object and converted all Amazon headers into query string parameters.

The actual implementation turned out to be much more difficult than I would have liked. Since Amazon's query string authentication only uses the "host" for `SignedHeaders` (whereas the AmazonAWS SDK was attempting to use host, date, and target) I had to re-compute the signature. This meant CryptoJS and lots of experimentation to get everything working.

After 4 hours of receiving "Computed signature did not match", I finally started getting a different error code: `Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized`

Googling this error [was not very helpful](https://www.google.com/search?q=Unable+to+determine+service%2Foperation+name+to+be+authorized): anything from a typo to an extra new-line character to using a datestamp instead of a version number. However I tried *everything* and nothing helped.

Below is an example cURL request and the return value:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data "{\"Data\":\"VALID BASE64 DATA\",\"PartitionKey\":\"PARTITION\",\"StreamName\":\"STREAM\"}" "https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAJMAGAYBGGRNZQI4A/20140723/us-east-1/kinesis/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20140723T153144Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Target=Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord&X-Amz-User-Agent=aws-sdk-js/2.0.0&X-Amz-Signature=VALID_SIGNATURE"
```

Return:

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

I've tried appending `Action` and `Version` parameters (noting that [the `Version` should be in YYYY-MM-DD format as opposed to YYYYMMDD](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/CommonParametersV4.html)) and this didn't help. I also tried escaping all of my `/` characters or escaping all of my `.` characters (or both).

For comparison, here's the same request through Google Chrome using headers instead of a query string:

```
Remote Address:176.32.102.203:443
Request URL:https://kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
Accept:* / *
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAJMAGAYBGGRNZQI4A/20140723/us-east-1/kinesis/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=OMITTED
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3236
Content-Type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
Host:kinesis.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Origin:OMITTED
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:OMITTED
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
X-Amz-Date:20140723T145554Z
X-Amz-Target:Kinesis_20131202.PutRecord
X-Amz-User-Agent:aws-sdk-js/2.0.0
Request Payload
OMITTED (because it's long)
```

Response:

```
{"SequenceNumber":"49540780386103606919741841581837328106424971136629473281","ShardId":"shardId-000000000000"}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong, and why I can't communicate with Kinesis?

Comment: It seems like your X-Amz-Signed-Headers=host suggests that you aren't signing enought "headers" -- query string parameters, in this case, X-Amz-Target and X-Amz-Date, at least.

Comment: According to [Amazon's own documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-get-query-string), `For requests that use query strings, only "host" is included in the signed headers.` (this is a comment shortly after "Step 3" in the Python code)

Comment: Good point, but note also that the docs you cite indicate they are for `GET` (not `POST`).  Try setting your curl Content-Type header to application/x-amz-json-1.1 if you haven't.  Kinesis seems to react differently when that's present vs. text/plain.  Beyond that, Plan B is to send your request to your application server and proxy it to kinesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through and cleaning up some old questions that never got answers.

Per Michael - sqlbot:

> Plan B is to send your request to your application server and proxy it to kinesis

This turned out to be the only solution for communicating with Kinesis. Set up a proxy which allowed me to pass custom headers as a query string, then it recombobulated it and sent the request onward